# How to generate id dynamically for json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js

I have my json part like this:

```
 {
    "INFO": {
        "01": {
            "Your Name": "Text"
        },
        "02": {
            "Date  Of Birth": "Text"
        },
        "03": {
            "Married": "YesNo"
        },
        "04": {
            "Gender M/F": "Radiobutton"
        }
    },
    "INFO SPOUSE": {
        "01": {
            "Your Name": "Text"
        },
        "02": {
            "Date  Of Birth": "Text"
        },
        "03": {
            "Married": "YesNo"
        },
        "04": {
            "Gender M/F": "Radiobutton"
        }
    }
}
```

Json is working fine in the front end.

Now, i want to generate dynamic id for the above json for each question so that i can use the id's value for backend purpose.

I want id based on the question number so that in backend i will get the value like (Your Name = xxx)

Am using handlebarrs.js

Comment: clarify a what structure you need exactly

Comment: I need id for the above code either in javascript.

Comment: I need id for the above code either in javascript or jquery so that in backend i will know the value what user has typed for the particular questions

Comment: my mean to say are you thinking for the structure like "INFO": {
        "01": {
            "Your Name": "Text"
        }, to "INFO": {
        {
          "id":"01",  "Your Name": "Text"
        },

Comment: can you explain it clearly am not able to understand

Answer (score 0):

just to explain(As comment box was not enough)

```
my mean to say that do you like to get your JSON in the given format {
"INFO": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "Your Name": "Text"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "Date  Of Birth": "Text"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "Married": "YesNo"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "Gender M/F": "Radiobutton"
    }
],
"INFO SPOUSE": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "Your Name": "Text"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "Date  Of Birth": "Text"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "Married": "YesNo"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "Gender M/F": "Radiobutton"
    }
]
```

}

if yes then you achieve it if in php(just by iterating the over object array(to which you can convert in to plan array by using json_decode($yourjsonstring ,true) function ) and making a new array from after your iteration by assigning the key values to id key lying inside inside info and Info spouse array ) , hope you get the idea a what i mean to say here .

Comment: no i need json in the format what i gave, if i use json as per your format will i get id also printed on the frontend because i will be using "each" and "key"